# Excel VBA sorting and filtering macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am extremely new at working with macros in Excel.  I used the 'Record Macro' feature in Excel 2016 to build a filter and sort macro for a single column and then iterated in the code editor.  I'm not sure what's wrong with it but it keeps crashing my program. The code is below.  Any help at all would be great.

```
Sub Filter()
'
' Filter Macro
' Filter workbook
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+A
'

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Uncategorized Products").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
        Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Uncategorized Products").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
        Add Key:=Range("B1:B62637"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending _
        , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Uncategorized Products").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Sheets("Uncategorized Products").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$62637").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="=0"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$62637").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"""


ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Missing Images").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
        Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Missing Images").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
        Add Key:=Range("B1:B62637"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending _
        , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Missing Images").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Sheets("Missing Images").Select
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$62637").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=FALSE"
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$62637").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"""

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RWI Settings").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
        Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RWI Settings").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
        Add Key:=Range("B1:B62637"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending _
        , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RWI Settings").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Sheets("RWI Settings").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$62637").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"""

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Names & Descriptions").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
        Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Names & Descriptions").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
        Add Key:=Range("A1:A62637"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending _
        , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Names & Descriptions").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Sheets("Names & Descriptions").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$62637").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=TRUE"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$62637").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"""

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Disabled Items").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
        Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Disabled Items").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
        Add Key:=Range("A1:A62637"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending _
        , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Disabled Items").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Sheets("Disabled Items").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$62637").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"""


    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Boost Scores").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
        Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Boost Scores").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
        Add Key:=Range("A1:A62637"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending _
        , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Boost Scores").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Sheets("Boost Scores").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$62637").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"""
End Sub
```

Fixed my issue.  New code that works pasted below:

Sub sort()
'
' sort Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
'
    Dim lastRow As Long

```
Sheets("Store Product Data").Activate
'Search for any entry, by searching backwards by Rows.
lastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

With Sheets("Uncategorized Products")
    With .Range("A2:F" & lastRow)
        .Formula = "=iferror(INDEX('Store Product Data'!$A:$R,'Key'!$A1+1,MATCH(A$1,'Store Product Data'!$A$1:$R$1,0)),0)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With

    With Sheets("Missing Images")
    With .Range("A2:E" & lastRow)
        .Formula = "=iferror(INDEX('Store Product Data'!$A:$R,'Key'!$A1+1,MATCH(A$1,'Store Product Data'!$A$1:$R$1,0)),0)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With

    With Sheets("RWI Settings")
    With .Range("A2:H" & lastRow)
        .Formula = "=iferror(INDEX('Store Product Data'!$A:$R,'Key'!$A1+1,MATCH(A$1,'Store Product Data'!$A$1:$R$1,0)),0)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With

    With Sheets("Names & Descriptions")
    With .Range("A2:E" & lastRow)
        .Formula = "=iferror(INDEX('Store Product Data'!$A:$R,'Key'!$A1+1,MATCH(A$1,'Store Product Data'!$A$1:$R$1,0)),0)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With

    With Sheets("Disabled Items")
    With .Range("A2:D" & lastRow)
        .Formula = "=iferror(INDEX('Store Product Data'!$A:$R,'Key'!$A1+1,MATCH(A$1,'Store Product Data'!$A$1:$R$1,0)),0)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With

        With Sheets("Boost Scores")
    With .Range("A2:E" & lastRow)
        .Formula = "=iferror(INDEX('Store Product Data'!$A:$R,'Key'!$A1+1,MATCH(A$1,'Store Product Data'!$A$1:$R$1,0)),0)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With

Sheets("Uncategorized Products").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Uncategorized Products").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Uncategorized Products").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("B1:B50000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending _
    , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Uncategorized Products").AutoFilter.sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Uncategorized Products").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Uncategorized Products").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("E1:E50000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Uncategorized Products").AutoFilter.sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Uncategorized Products").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Uncategorized Products").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("F1:F50000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Uncategorized Products").AutoFilter.sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

    Sheets("Missing Images").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Missing Images").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Missing Images").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("A1:A50000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending _
    , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Missing Images").AutoFilter.sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Missing Images").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Missing Images").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("D1:D50000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Missing Images").AutoFilter.sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Missing Images").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Missing Images").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("E1:E50000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Missing Images").AutoFilter.sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

        Sheets("RWI Settings").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RWI Settings").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RWI Settings").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("B1:B50000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending _
    , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RWI Settings").AutoFilter.sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RWI Settings").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RWI Settings").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("A1:A50000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RWI Settings").AutoFilter.sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

        Sheets("Names & Descriptions").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Names & Descriptions").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Names & Descriptions").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("A1:A50000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending _
    , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Names & Descriptions").AutoFilter.sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Names & Descriptions").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Names & Descriptions").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("B1:B50000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Names & Descriptions").AutoFilter.sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Names & Descriptions").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Names & Descriptions").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("e1:e50000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Names & Descriptions").AutoFilter.sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

        Sheets("Disabled Items").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Disabled Items").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Disabled Items").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("A1:A50000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending _
    , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Disabled Items").AutoFilter.sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Disabled Items").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Disabled Items").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("D1:D50000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Disabled Items").AutoFilter.sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

        Sheets("Boost Scores").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Boost Scores").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Boost Scores").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("A1:A50000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending _
    , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Boost Scores").AutoFilter.sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Boost Scores").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Boost Scores").AutoFilter.sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("D1:D50000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Boost Scores").AutoFilter.sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Are you getting an error and if so, what line of code?

Comment: Also, does your data go down to row 62637?

Comment: Hey.  I actually just found a better way to do this a little while ago that works.  Code pasted in the original post.